# How to initialize a sockaddr_in struct with a single line of code?

Tags: c, networking

Using a C89/C99 compiler, these two lines of code work

```
struct sockaddr_in server = { AF_INET, htons(27015), INADDR_ANY};
server.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");
```

Is there a shorter version? For example, these do not work:

```
struct sockaddr_in server = { AF_INET, htons(27015), INADDR_ANY, inet_addr("127.0.0.1")};
struct sockaddr_in server = { AF_INET, htons(27015), INADDR_ANY, .sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1") };
```

This unsightly long version works fine

```
struct sockaddr_in server;
server.sin_family = AF_INET;
server.sin_port = htons(27015);
server.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
server.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");
```

The sockaddr_in has this format:

```
typedef struct sockaddr_in {
    short   sin_family;
    USHORT  sin_port;
    IN_ADDR sin_addr;
    CHAR    sin_zero[8];
} SOCKADDR_IN, *PSOCKADDR_IN;
```

**Windows Client**

https://godbolt.org/z/8q8GPxP54

**Windows Server**

https://godbolt.org/z/8j3ozKKxP

This suggested code does not connect

```
struct sockaddr_in server = { AF_INET, htons(27015), {inet_addr("127.0.0.1")}, {0} };
```

This code does connect

```
struct sockaddr_in serverX;
serverX.sin_family = AF_INET;
serverX.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
serverX.sin_port = htons(27015);
serverX.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");
```

Here's the difference between the versions. Notice, s_addr in server struct is 0x0000007f, whereas it's 0x0100007f in serverX:

[image: trace]

Comment: *How to initialize a sockaddr_in struct with a single line of code?*  And get kicked out of every code review for unnecessarily making everyone's life harder because you wrote hard-to-understand, bug-prone code by cramming it all into one line.  Anyone saying things like "brevity of code" is just chanting a cargo-cult aphorism.  Write maintainable, easy-to-understand code no matter how many lines it takes.

Comment: Why did the htons() call work but not inet_addr()?

Comment: Unlike inet_addr, htons is a macro.

Comment: @StephanSchlecht The standard does not restrict initializers to constant expressions on the basis of whether a designator is present.

Comment: @dbush I assumed that it is defined outside a function - therefore htons can be used and inet_addr cannot. Still, you're right, my general wording is wrong/misleading. I deleted the comment.

Comment: I think @dbush is very close to a solution with the suggested initializers. However, there's a slight adjustment needed somewhere. I've re-edited with some debugging. Thanks!

Comment: @vengy As I stated in my updated answer, it doesn't work on Windows because `struct in_addr` is defined differently.  It's better to assign to `s_addr` to make code more portable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things: first, you've got the initalizer for `sin_addr` in the wrong place.  It's the third element in the struct, so the initializer should be third.  Second, since `sin_addr` is a struct type, you need to put its initializer in braces as well.

So what you want is:

```
struct sockaddr_in server={ AF_INET, htons(27015), {inet_addr("127.0.0.1")}, {0}};
```

As was mentioned in the comments however, condensing code onto one line usually isn't good practice because it can make code harder to read.  Personally I'd prefer the long version as it makes it more clear to the reader which fields are being initialized with what.

Also note that this will only work on systems where the `.s_addr` field is defined as a macro, as many systems do.  For example, Windows (which you appear to be using) defines `struct in_addr` as follows:

```
struct in_addr {
        union {
                struct { u_char s_b1,s_b2,s_b3,s_b4; } S_un_b;
                struct { u_short s_w1,s_w2; } S_un_w;
                u_long S_addr;
        } S_un;
#define s_addr  S_un.S_addr
                                /* can be used for most tcp & ip code */
#define s_host  S_un.S_un_b.s_b2
                                /* host on imp */
#define s_net   S_un.S_un_b.s_b1
                                /* network */
#define s_imp   S_un.S_un_w.s_w2
                                /* imp */
#define s_impno S_un.S_un_b.s_b4
                                /* imp # */
#define s_lh    S_un.S_un_b.s_b3
                                /* logical host */
};
```

As do many older UNIX distributions.

So to reiterate, use the code that's the most clear to the reader, not what fits on one line.